# How to suppress tar error messages in when piping

Tags: command-line, tar

For example:
I extract a tar.bz2 file with tar -xvf instead of tar -xjvf:

```
 tar -xvf file.tar.bz2
 tar: invalid tar magic
```

and if redirect stderr

```
 tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 2>/dev/null
```

it works.

Now if I use a pipe

```
 tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 | grep "something" 2>/dev/null 
 tar: invalid tar magic
```

Here if the first command fails I cannot suppress the error.

Is there a way to suppress in this way

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it works". Note that ignoring this error won't "solve" the problem... The reason you're getting the error is that the *.bz2 file is not a tar file so the type-check (tar magic code at the beginning) fails.  Also a `grep` on stdout won't actually search the contents of the extracted files.  Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are couple of alternatives that involve redirecting STDERR of both `tar` and `grep` :

- Use `bash` command grouping `{}`:

  ```
  { tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 | grep "something" ;} 2>/dev/null
  ```
- Using a subshell `()` :

  ```
  ( tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 | grep "something" ) 2>/dev/null
  ```

Note that if you want to redirect STDERR of a single process its better to use [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/668032/216503) instead.

On a different note, if you want to `grep` something over both the STDOUT and STDERR of `tar` use :

```
tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 |& grep "something"
```

This will also cause the STDERR of `tar` to be exhausted.

This is actually a shorthand for :

```
tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 2>&1 | grep "something"
```

Answer (score 6):

The pipe forms a separate clause in the command so the redirection in...

```
tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 | grep "something" 2>/dev/null
```

...is redirecting the STDERR from `grep`, not `tar`.

To fix, simply reorder things so your redirect is with your `tar` command:

```
tar -xvf file.tar.bz2 2>/dev/null | grep "something"
```